# SQL subtraction code works in SQL but not in sqldatasource

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, gridview, sql-server-2012

I'm scratching my head over this one as I can get this code to work in SQL but when I transfer it to a simple gridview the code errors out stating 'Invalid Object name tablename'.

What I'm attempting to do is take a static number and subtract it from three different columns in the same table.

This is what I have that works within SQL:

```
SELECT

(3000)
- 

(SELECT COUNT(column1) from table1 where column1 = 'Agreed') 

+

(SELECT COUNT(column2) from table1 where column2 = 'Agreed')

+

(SELECT COUNT(column3) from table1 where column3 = 'Agreed')

AS subtract
```

I've tried moving the static total around as such

```
(3000)

- 

SELECT

(SELECT COUNT(column1) from table1 where column1 = 'Agreed') 

+

(SELECT COUNT(column2) from table1 where column2 = 'Agreed')

+

(SELECT COUNT(column3) from table1 where column3 = 'Agreed')

AS subtract
```

And....

'3000'

```
- 

SELECT

(SELECT COUNT(column1) from table1 where column1 = 'Agreed') 

+

(SELECT COUNT(column2) from table1 where column2 = 'Agreed')

+

(SELECT COUNT(column3) from table1 where column3 = 'Agreed')

AS subtract
```

But both return syntax errors in SQL.

What I'm hoping to get is the remainder of taking the totals of the three select statements from the static number.

Am I missing something simple here? I'm stumped as to why this would work within SQL but not when I transfer the code to a gridview.

**::edit::**

See Answer below for the solution.  Had to re-write the code to get it to work.

```
SELECT 

(3000) 
- 
a.c 
+ 
b.c 
+ 
c.c 

from (SELECT COUNT(*) AS c from table1 where column1 = 'Agreed') a 
left join (SELECT COUNT(*) AS c from table1 where column2 = 'Agreed') b on 1=1 
left join (SELECT COUNT(*) AS c from table1 where column3 = 'Agreed') c on 1=1
```

Comment: How are you using this code in a gridview? Do you mean an sqldatasource?

Comment: Yes, a sqldatasource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first and second queries are not the same at all :

```
SELECT 3000  - 10
```

Is not the same that :

```
3000 - SELECT 10
```

The second one is not valid because it do not begin by the `SELECT` statement (as you did in the first). It is not a ASP.NET specifiec issue.

EDIT :

What about this query :

```
SELECT

(3000)
- 
a.c
+
b.c
+
c.c

from (SELECT COUNT(*) AS c from table1 where column1 = 'Agreed') AS a 
left join (SELECT COUNT(*) AS c from table1 where column2 = 'Agreed') AS b on 1=1
left join (SELECT COUNT(*) AS c from table1 where column3 = 'Agreed') AS c on 1=1
```

Comment: This doesn't help me at all.  I get that they're different.  However, it doesn't resolve the initial issue of the first piece of code working in SQL and not in an asp page with sqldatasource/gridview.  That's why I downvoted.

Comment: They are not only different, the last two will never work. I didn't saw you "tried" with them, I tought you "used" them in ASP.NET. I'll have a look a bit closer.

Comment: I couldn't think of any other variations of the code that would work.  I had to try something.

Comment: Getting syntax errors on the c in the first select statement the b in the second select statement and the c in the third select statement.  suggestions?  Looking over documentation now.

Comment: @TechieJoe I runned this exact query and this is valid (SQL SERVER 2008). What did you exactly runned ? Can you display me the entire exception ?

Comment: As noted above I'm running this in Sql 2012.  The error in the browser is System.Sata.SqlClient.SqlException: Incorrect syntax near 'c'.  Incorrect syntax near 'b'.  Incorrect syntax near 'c'.  The error in sql is Msg 102 with the same 'Incorrect syntax...' errors above.  I'm running the code exactly as noted above.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46449/discussion-between-cubitouch-and-techie-joe)